# example of embeddeding xterm in wxPython panel

Tags: wxpython, xterm

I'm looking for an example or advice for embedding an xterm window in a wxPython panel. I think I can get the window ID of a panel with something like "wid=somePanel.GetHandle()" and I should be able to pass that to "xterm -use wid" but so far I'm not having much luck making that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple script that does work on my machine (ubuntu 8/python 2.5.2/wxpython2.8.10)

```
import wx
import os

def bindXterm(win):
    winID = win.GetHandle()
    print "binding xterm to window %d(%x)"%(winID,winID)
    os.system("xterm -inot %d"%winID)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
xtermFrame = wx.Frame(None)
xtermPanel = wx.Panel(xtermFrame)
xtermPanel.SetBackgroundColour((255,0,0))
app.SetTopWindow(xtermFrame)
xtermFrame.Show()
wx.CallLater(1000, bindXterm, xtermPanel)
app.MainLoop()
```

Two things to note are

1. My xterm have only -into option, use
   the window id given to -into as the
   parent window rather than the
   default root window
2. We can't just attach xterm before
   starting the app, so using calllater
   and it works fine

Comment: Thanks. In a rare moment of lucidity I realized why my code wasn't working -- I was trying to embed an xterm in a OSX cocoa-based version of wxPython. This code works fine on my linux box, though I'm surprised that "-inot" works. Shouldn't that be "-into"?